# Get HTML div element by its attribute and value using query selector API

Tags: html, typescript

I have below div in my HTML.

```
<div row-index="0" /div>
<div row-index="1" /div>
```

I have to select specific div from above using its attribute. I am trying to do below in my typescript code. I get this index 0, 1 from another object.

```
const value = event.rowIndex;  -->line 1
const elem = document.querySelector('[row-index= value]'); -->line 2
```

The 'value' in line 2 upon hovering in my webstorm IDE says cannot find declaration to go to. I want it to use value from line1. Do I have to escape it using some backslash or quotations or something?

Comment: FYI, `row-index` is not a valid attribute on a div element. If you're using it arbitrarily you should covert it to a data attribute, as `data-row-index`.

Comment: @isherwood I do not think what you said is correct. I am using an ag-grid library and it generates the divs for rows in such manner.

Comment: It's not valid just because someone else does it. :) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#attributes.

Comment: AG Grid uses the row ARIA role, so maybe that excuses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just drop a variable into a selector like that. You'll need to use concatenation or a template literal.

```
querySelector('[row-index="' + value + '"]')
```